# Inconsistent tag naming for insurance

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, tag-renaming

There is inconsistent tag naming between [insurance](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insurance) and [travel-insurance-claim](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-insurance-claim).

Travel-insurance is a synonym of insurance but travel-insurance-claim doesn’t have an insurance-claim synonym.

We need to synchronise the tags.

- Make both tags contain travel or not
- Make the other a synonym

I think we need to keep travel in the tag, since we are a travel site and do not handle car or personal insurance questions.

I propose:

- Have travel-insurance and travel-insurance-claims tags
- Have insurance and insurance-claims synonyms

Answer (score 2):

I'll debate against using the "travel-" prefix.

This is a travel site and the domain is travel.stackexchange.com. I think that makes travel implicit and there's no need for explicit prefixes, like [travel-law](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-law), [travel-airplane](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-airplane), [travel-passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-passport) etc.

I don't expect this answer to get upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

I think that travel-insurance and insurance are different tags which can refer to different things: car insurance whilst on a road trip comes to mind. I think the two are distinct topics and should be kept separate.

I would merge *-claims with the corresponding * since those are indeed redundant.